# convert sql query in to laravel5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am doing the miles search. I ahve done the miles search in core sql query but i want to convert it into laravel query . Can anyone help me :-
Here is my DB structure

```
Users table

id name
1  abc
2   def

Listings Table

id user_id  name   latitude    longitude
1   1      test    30.9193     75.8309
2   2      new     30.9177     75.8415
```

Now i have make join of users and listings table actually i am doing the miles searching but i want to implement with laravel query
Here is my laravel query:-

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('listings','users.id','=','listings.user_id')
        ->select('users.id','users.service_name','listings.id as listid','listings.latitude','listings.longitude')
        ->get();
```

Now i have the Core sql query but i want to combine with above query:-

```
enter code here
$sql = SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(30.9193) ) * cos( radians( 
lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(75.8309) ) + sin ( radians(30.9193) 
) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM listings HAVING distance <
```

76
Can anyone help me how to add in the laravel above query. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try whereRaw

```
$nearby = Listings::whereRaw("(
                                        3959 
                                        *DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS('30.9193'))
                                        * COS(RADIANS(lat))
                                        * COS(RADIANS('75.8309' - lng))+ SIN (RADIANS('30.9193'))         
                                        * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))<=5)"
                                        )->paginate(50);
```

In your case

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('listings','users.id','=','listings.user_id')
        ->select('users.id','users.service_name','listings.id as listid','listings.latitude','listings.longitude')
        ->whereRaw("(
                                            3959 
                                            *DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS('30.9193'))
                                            * COS(RADIANS(listings.latitude))
                                            * COS(RADIANS('75.8309' - listings.longitude))+ SIN (RADIANS('30.9193'))         
                                            * SIN(RADIANS(listings.longitude))))<=76)"
                                            )
        ->get();
```

Comment: i want join listings with users

Comment: In this COS(RADIANS(lat) piece of code it will listings.lat or simply lat ?

Comment: Should be listings.latitude

Comment: You dont have any aggregate functions , so you do not need any having clause there. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

When your query is to complex, then try `RAW` query in Laravel like:

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw('Your SQL query'));
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

**Note:** These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points

Comment: But i want in laravel query?

Comment: `DB::select(DB::raw())` is also Laravel query function

Comment: so what would be my final query with join